# Is it possible to read from Azure Log Analytics workspace using Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I would like to know if a connector exists to access Azure Log Analytics workspaces from Apache Spark.  I know that [azure-kusto-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark) can access a Kusto cluster from Azure Data Explorer, but can the same connector be used to connect to Log Analytics workspaces?  I was under the impression that Log Analytics was built on top of Data Explorer...

I tried to use azure-kusto-spark, but the only configuration it seems to support is cluster-based, nothing about workspace names like it would be for Log Analytics.

Comment: should be fixed in next version

Comment: @OhadBitton Are you saying that this error will be fixed in the next release, making Log Analytics workspaces accessible via Spark using that connector?  Or even with this error fixed, we still won't be able to access Log Analytics because there are other missing pieces?  Is it related to this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/issues/223

Comment: @ladoe00, if you read the docs here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/docs/KustoSource.md#source-read-command you can see that in single mode the connector uses the query endpoint and in that mode it can work against a LogAnalytics workspace. In distributed mode (required for scale) the connector uses the export capabilities to enable multi node to multi node data transfers. As the control commends are not supported on LogAnalytics workspaces, distributed mode is not supported.

Comment: Fixed in version 3.0.0

Comment: In order to access a LogAnalytics workspace table, you need to access it via a Data Explorer cluster as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data).  Once this is done, you can usr URLs like `https://ade.loganalytics.io/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/<workspace-name>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in case anyone is looking for one like I was

```
df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource") \
    .option("kustoCluster", "https://ade.loganalytics.io/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my_resource_group/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/my-log-anlytics-workspace-name") \
    .option("kustoDatabase", "my-log-anlytics-workspace-name") \
    .option("kustoQuery", "ADXQuery |take 10") \
    .option("kustoAadAppId", "service-principal-app-client-id") \
    .option("kustoAadAppSecret",dbutils.secrets.get(scope="key-vault-secrets",key="service-principal-secret")) \
    .option("kustoAadAuthorityID", "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47") \
    .load()
```